# Combination of START /WAIT and /B possible?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm facing a quite stupid problem. I have a list of commands generated by a NAnt script. These are stored in a bat file. In each line I'm calling an exe with several parameters. The exe operates on a set of files and modifies them. The set of files is always the same. We are talking about ~1000 calls of the exe so if each time a new console would pop up I'd get performance issues. "No problem" I thought and added `START /B` to each command line so now the exe is started in background which works way faster.
Now here's the problem: As I've mentioned, the exe operates on the same set of files so sometimes it happens that a file can't be modified because it's already opened by a different instance of the program which results in a crash. I'd like to add the `/W` parameter to each call to ensure that never two instances run at the same time. But this somehow disables the `/B` parameter.

So my question is: is it possible to have my exe started in background AND force my batch to wait for each instance to terminate?

**Please don't tell me that this is ugly. I know but I can't change anything about the setup. My company has been working with this s*** for years and the only point where I can make modifications is the generated bat file.**

Here is the code of the generated bat:

```
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
...
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
start /B /W S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1 --param2 "XYZ" --param3 "ZYX" --param4 "1 2 3" --param5 "321" --param6 "1337" --param7
```

Comment: When you start `exe.exe` without anything, does it opens a new window? `Start /b /wait` should be the same as starting it directly.

Comment: @jeb You're right, it's actually `start`. I've edited my post. Yes, the exe.exe opens a new console. The exe itself takes only some milliseconds to finish but it takes way longer to open and close the console which I'm avoiding with `/B`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/355342/439537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `start /b` without `/wait` and build your own synchronizing.

This waits until the file `lock.tmp` is no longer locked by the `start` command.

This example uses calc.exe for demonstration.
It can be useful to use the ping command to wait a second, as without ping the cpu usage will go up to 100%.
But my test says that the cpu is only at 5% while waiting.

```
@echo off

call :syncExecute
call :syncExecute
call :syncExecute
exit /b

:::::::::::::
:syncExecute
( start /b c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe ) > lock.tmp
:waitForExit
(
  REM ping -n 2 localhost > nul
  echo dummy > lock.tmp
) 2> nul || goto :waitForExit
exit /b
```

**EDIT: Solution with direct waiting**

This uses the fact that a pipe will block until the producer is finished.
This solution doesn't needs extra cpu performance in a waiting loop and it can start the next job immediately after a job is finished.

```
@echo off

call :syncExecute
call :syncExecute
call :syncExecute
exit /b

:::::::::::::
:syncExecute
( start /b c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe ) | more > nul
exit /b
```

Comment: I've been talking about performance issues and about ~1000 executions. Ping with 1 second will result in > ~1000 seconds of waiting time. Otherwise it's a busy-wait construction which is the biggest performance issue of all times :(

Comment: However, thank you for your proposal, using a lock is a nice idea.

Comment: If you use a multi core, than it's not a problem to use `start` with the `AFFINITY` option. The 100% is only for one core, the exe will run on another core

Comment: OK, this should work. And I will take this solution if there won't be a better one. Thank you! Would you be so kind and add your last comment to your answer?

Comment: Suprisingly the cpu only goes up to 5% on my system when using the waiting with a loop

Comment: Ooh - I like the pipe block technique

Answer (score 1):

You may use a file as a *flag* to detect that the .exe file is running. Create the flag file before each execution of the .exe and remove it when the .exe ends. This way, the Batch file just needs to wait for the flag file to disappear before start the next .exe:

```
echo X > flag.txt
start "" /B "S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1  ...  --param7  &  del flag.txt"
call :waitForProcess
echo X > flag.txt
start "" /B "S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1  ...  --param7  &  del flag.txt"
call :waitForProcess
...
echo X > flag.txt
start "" /B "S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1  ...  --param7  &  del flag.txt"
call :waitForProcess
echo X > flag.txt
start "" /B "S:\ome\path\to\my\exe.exe --param1  ...  --param7  &  del flag.txt"
call :waitForProcess

goto :EOF

:waitForProcess
ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
if exist flag.txt goto waitForProcess
exit /B
```

For better performance, you may adjust the `ping` waiting time in `:waitForProcess` subroutine so it waits approximately the same time that the .exe takes to end. If the .exe takes just milliseconds, you may entirely omit the `ping` command.

Comment: This will not work, as the `del flag.txt` will execute immediatly, before exe.exe is finished. Therefore I used a redirection instead. You can test it with calc.exe

Comment: This is quite the same as jeb's answer above. Ping is not an potion because we're talking about ~1000 executions so waiting 1 second would mean a total of at least 1000 seconds waiting time. Busy waiting would work and I will use it if there is no better way.

Comment: By the way, instead of using a file as a flag you can as well check the running tasks for "exe.exe".

Comment: @jeb: The .exe is separated of the `del flag.txt` command by an `&` character, so the `del` is executed until the .exe is terminated.

Comment: @MichaelS: Excuse me. Did you tested this method? It will not works? In such a case, please describe the behaviour so I can fix it...

Comment: I tried it with the ampersand and it failed. The START itself is finished immediately so the ampersand haven't the desired effect

Comment: @jeb: `start` command does not wait for the .exe if it is a 32-bit GUI application (like calc.exe) as explained in the start help. However, a 32-bit GUI program always create a new window even if /B switch is used, so the OP's `exe.exe` program is not of this type and hence the `&  del flag.txt` part will be executed until the exe.exe program terminates.

Comment: @Aacini & jeb: This is not the question. This might or might not work as you've suggested. However, instead of using a file on the HDD it's faster to check if the exe is running with this code: `@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
SET running=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"exe.exe"') DO SET running=1
IF %running%==1 GOTO LOOP`  However, it's a busy-wait construction and even if it takes only 5% usage of a single core, I hope there is a more elegant way.

Comment: @MichaelS: **1.** Your proposed code executes tasklist.exe and findstr.exe external files in each loop, plus at least one additional copy of cmd.exe in order to execute the piped commands in `FOR /f`. My solution use just one internal `if exist` command to do the same thing. **2.** The "elegant way" is a subjective term; for example, in my opinion the most elegant solution is the simplest one. You had no posted additional requirements when you did the bounty. **3.** I think that a simple way to check solutions is to perform tests based on a given point; for example, the CPU usage percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I think there is a confusion here.

`START` command is used to run more than one instance of a given program *in parallel* (asynchronous way) with other instances of the same program. When `START` command is used with the /Wait switch, then the final result is the same as if the `START` command is entirely omitted. The commands placed in a Batch file are executed in sequential way: the next one starts until the previous one ends. This is the same result you get if you execute the same commands without `START /W`.

I think you will solve your problem if you omit the `start /B /W` part in the commands stored in the generated Batch file. The execution of the .exe file should not open a new cmd.exe window, but if it does that, then the `start` command have not a way to avoid that behaviour! Could you give us more details about this point?

Comment: Unfortunately the exe does open a new cmd window. That's why I've tried `start /b`. But `start /b` runs several instances in parallel (as you've pointed out). To avoid this race condition I'd like to use `/wait`. So my problem is not about `start /wait` but about `/b`. I suppose you are right that this won't work with `start`. Do you have other suggestions how to run my exe 1000 times sequential while suppressing new windows? I know that there's a way using VB script but this is also way too slow.